# Can the Alert Dialog box change the colors of other aspect with a text button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Current code. I want when done is pressed, the elevated button should change colors from grey to yellow

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Fall 2022'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(37, 57, 92, 1.0),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'CSC 1351',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(37, 57, 92, 1.0),
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                      title: Text('CSC 1351'),
                      content: Text(
                          'Intro to Computer Science for CS Majors \n \n9:30am - 10:30am  M W F Lecture    Shark, E \n stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff'),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text('Ongoing'),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text('Done'),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
```

Current code. I want when the text button "done" is pressed, the elevated button should change colors from grey to yellow

Answer (score 0):

to do this you can get the value return by the dialog. Once you get the return value, just need to use `setState` method to update your widget tree. (Dont forget to use a StatefulWidget to have access to `setState` method).

Here an example:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color _elevatedButtonColor = Color.fromRGBO(37, 57, 92, 1.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Fall 2022'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(37, 57, 92, 1.0),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'CSC 1351',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: _elevatedButtonColor,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                      title: Text('CSC 1351'),
                      content: Text(
                          'Intro to Computer Science for CS Majors \n \n9:30am - 10:30am  M W F Lecture    Shark, E \n stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff'),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text('Ongoing'),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
                              context, false), //pop the dialog and return false
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text('Done'),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
                              context, true), //pop the dialog and return true
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ).then((value) => {
                        //when dialog is closed enter this function
                        if (value == true)
                          {
                            //if dialog return true you change the button color
                            setState(() {
                              _elevatedButtonColor = Colors.yellow;
                            })
                          }
                      });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```